# Green's theorem in divergence form and its line integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

$$
\int_C F \times da
$$

$$
 k\iint_R \operatorname{div} F \ dx \, dy
$$

Hi

Let $F$ be two-dimensional vector field. State a definition for the vector-valued line integral so that your definition would be such that the above formula is a consequence of green's theorem. (the above integrals are same)

$k$ is usual $(0,0,1)$ vector.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What are $da$, $C$ and $R$ exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If $$F=F_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+F_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$ then $$\int_CF\times da = k \int_C(F_1\, dy - F_2 \, dx).$$
Now apply [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem#Theorem).

Comment: I am not sure how to apply green's what is F x da .?

Comment: If $C$ is parameterized by $(x(t), y(t))$ then $F \times da$ is $(F_1, F_2, 0)\times(\dot{x}, \dot{y},0)$ where $\times$ is the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$.